# Select Query com AJAX e PHP

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em php e possuo uma página onde ele lista vários resultados de um `SELECT`, até aí tudo bem... e eu tenho um `input text` onde eu gostaria que cada letra que eu fosse digitando nele, os resultados fossem sendo filtrados de acordo com a letra que eu digitei, por exemplo: digitei A vão aparecer todos os resultados que comecem com A, se eu digitar uma segunda letra (E por exemplo) em seguida do A, apareceriam resultados que houvessem no começo do nome AE, claro sem ter que ficar recarregando a página.
Imagino que isso seja feito com AJAX, qual é o nome disso e como posso fazer?

Comment: tem o [typeahead do titter](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) que faz exatamente isso. Mas se procurar por live search tambem acha bastente coisa sobre o assunto

Comment: Muito obrigado.... eu sou iniciante ainda no desenvolvimento... estou me virando, qual vc recomendaria pra mim ? eu apenas preciso disso mesmo sem muitas outras coisas, o basicao dessa função mesmo..

Comment: eu irira com essa do twitter mesmo, ja ta mercado faz tempo, nao é muito complicado e é relativamente flixilvel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exemplo :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q="+str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Comece a escrever o nome</b></p>
<form> 
Nome: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
</form>
<p>Sugestões: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

gethint.php

```
<?php
// Array com os nomes
$a[] = "Anna";
$a[] = "Brittany";
$a[] = "Cinderella";
$a[] = "Diana";
$a[] = "Eva";
$a[] = "Fiona";
$a[] = "Gunda";
$a[] = "Hege";
$a[] = "Inga";
$a[] = "Johanna";
$a[] = "Kitty";
$a[] = "Linda";
$a[] = "Nina";
$a[] = "Ophelia";
$a[] = "Petunia";
$a[] = "Amanda";
$a[] = "Raquel";
$a[] = "Cindy";
$a[] = "Doris";
$a[] = "Eve";
$a[] = "Evita";
$a[] = "Sunniva";
$a[] = "Tove";
$a[] = "Unni";
$a[] = "Violet";
$a[] = "Liza";
$a[] = "Elizabeth";
$a[] = "Ellen";
$a[] = "Wenche";
$a[] = "Vicky";

// pega o parâmetro q da URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$hint = "";

if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = $name;
            } else {
                $hint .= ", $name";
            }
        }
    }
}


echo $hint === "" ? "Sem sugestão" : $hint;
?>
```

[Teste Aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_ajax_php)

Espero que ajude.